# Breusch-Godfrey autocorrelation test: bgtest for panel data yields different results than pbgtest

Tags: panel-data, autocorrelation, plm

I have a panel data containing 12 different years, many id:s per year (some id:s missing in some years..unbalanced panel) and many variables. I'd like to test for auto correlation and I have run some regression models in OLS containing "year" variable to control for time. I have checked auto correlation by using `lmtest::bgtest` and it suggests no auto correlation (my data is in yearly order..2002,2002,2002,2003,2003....). I learned that the `plm`-package has function `pbgtest` which should be the same as `bgtest` but when I run the exact same OLS model in plm and test for auto correlation, the test suggests autocorrelation. Im using `model = "pooling"` in my plm function, so it should be exactly the same as my OLS model created by the lm-function. I'd like to know which one of the test to use/trust and why do the results differ?

example of my model:

```
a <- plm(y~x,model="pooling")
b <- lm(y~x)
plm::pbgtest(a)
lmtest::bgtest(b)
```

Test results are not the same although data is the same and summary for `a` and `b` are same. The difference is not due to different `order` or `type= "F"` or `"Chisq"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `order` has different default values when you use `pbgtest()` compared to `bgtest()`.

For `pbgtest()` `order = NULL`, for `bgtest()` `order = 1`.
See also the section Note in the documentation (`?pbgtest`).

What you want for a panel model the answer from `pbgtest()` (no matter what you want `order` to be).

However, you will not get the same numbers for both functions if you apply it to a panel model (fixed or random effects). This has a rather technical reason: `lmtest::bgtest` takes the data from `model_object$model` which are the original (untransformed) data in any case. For panel models, the test needs to be run on the (quasi-)demeaned data and `pbgtest()` being a wrapper around `lmtest::bgtest()` does excatly that: extract the (quasi-)demeaned data and pass them on to `lmtest::bgtest()`. For a pooling model, you will get the same numbers as the data are not transformed.

Please also note that the data in models estimated by `plm` might be in a different order as plm re-orders the data to be a stacked time series. To check that, one can compare the data and its order used in estimation by looking at `plm_object$model` and `lm_object$model`. A different order of observations will lead to differnt results of `pbgtest` and `bgtest` even for pooling models.

Here is a code example how `pbgtest()` works in principle:

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
g_re <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld, model = "random")

# extract (quasi-)demeanded data:
X <- model.matrix(g_re)
y <- pmodel.response(g_re)
# make a lm model object to be passed on to lmtest::bgtest()
lm.mod <- lm(y ~ X - 1)

# same coefficients:
all.equal(lm.mod$coefficients, g_re$coefficients, check.attributes = FALSE)
lmtest::bgtest(lm.mod, order = 1)
plm::pbgtest(g_re, order = 1) # identical results
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried same orders but they dont match. Bgtest implies no autocorrelation while pbgtest implies autocorrelation.

Comment: When you estimate a model with `plm`, your data is re-ordered if not already in the order `plm` uses. If you estimate with `lm`, no re-odering is performed, the model estimates will be the same, tough. However, what is forwared by `pbgtest` to `bgtest` is then in a different order compared to applying `bgtest` directly to your lm object. Maybe that is the reason?

Comment: You can check the ordering by looking at `plm_object$model` and `lm_object$model`.

Comment: Please also check, the argument for `plm` your are looking for is `model = "pooling"`, not `type = "pooling"`, you can check that you estimated a pooling model by `summary(plm_object)` and looking at its first rows.

Comment: Hey, thanks that ordering solves the problem. In plm the data gets in correct order i.e the function recognizes panel structure of the data correctly while in bgtest i didnt have the panel structure. In bgtest i just told the function that observations are in timely order but they werent due the panel structure.